# Using PowerBI (DAX) to calculate recurrent customers, getting computational error

Tags: powerbi, dax

My objective is to make a column that states whether a customer is recurrent.

I have made functional code (that works with 200 rows) that achieves this, which you can see here:

```
ReturningCustomer = 
VAR mycount = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(orders),
FILTER(
    ALLEXCEPT(orders, orders[Column1.Customer_ID]),
orders[Column1.BookingDate] < EARLIER(orders[Column1.BookingDate]
) ) )
RETURN IF (mycount > 0 && orders[Column1.OrderStatus] = "Active", "Yes")
```

My problem is, however, that I have about 45,000 rows in my dataset, and when running this it takes around 15 minutes, and then gives me the following computational error:

[Computational error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJzfm.png)

What part of the code makes this so computationally hard, and can it be done differently?

Comment: I not well versed in DAX so I cannot give advise on how to improve performance of your query, but maybe you could outsource the recurrence calculation to the import phase with the Power Query M language?

Comment: Can you add some example data,

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering so far. I will try to explain further. The columns i want to look at is Booking date, Customer ID - so by looking at these two columns i want to examine whether that particular customer, has booked before (so a previous booking date with same customer no.) So say for example i have 2 different booking dates for customer no. 10, this would mean that the latest order should have a column with returning customer = Yes.

Comment: Add your sample data in tabular format with your expected output.

Comment: | ID | Date | OrderStatus | ReturningCustomer 
1 | 13-08-2019  | Active      |   No
2 | 20-08-2019  | Active      |   No
2 | 25-08-2019  | Terminated  No
3 | 26-08-2019  | Active      |   No
1 | 16-08-2019  | Active      |   Yes
5 | 20-08-2019  | Active      |   No
6 | 21-08-2019  | Terminated  No
7 | 27-08-2019  | Active      |   No
8 | 20-08-2019  | Active      |   No    
1 | 25-08-2019  | Active      |   Yes               

Hope you understand, thank you so far - so my output is the column "Returning Customer". EDIT: this looks bad, check link: https://imgur.com/a/p9Nyiyy

Comment: have you tried to use the Performance analyzer tool (in the view section of powerbi desktop) to see what happens?